# How to change the selection of the second picker after changing the first picker?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-picker

Here I'm trying to create the first little app that helps to convert a value from one unit of measurement to another.
The first conversion picker helps me to select data for the second picker(from which measure I'm going to converse) and the third picker(to which measure I'm going converse).
But when I'm changing the first picker - it doesn't change the @State value of the second and third pickers. I tried different approaches but the result is the same. Could you please help me?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var userInput = 0.0
    
    @State var selectionOfTypeOfConversion: Conversions = .temperature
    @State var selectionFromConversion: String = TemperatureConversions.celsius.rawValue
    @State var selectionToConversion: String = TemperatureConversions.celsius.rawValue
    @FocusState private var inputIsFocused: Bool
    
    var output: Double {
        //doing all counting
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker("Type of conversion", selection: $selectionOfTypeOfConversion) {
                            ForEach(Conversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0.rawValue)

                            }
                        }.onSubmit {
                            checkConvention()
                        }
                        TextField("", value: $userInput, format: .number)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .focused($inputIsFocused)
                        Picker("From conversion", selection: $selectionFromConversion) {
                            switch selectionOfTypeOfConversion {
                            case Conversions.temperature:
                                ForEach(TemperatureConversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0.rawValue)
                                }
                            case Conversions.length:
                                ForEach(LengthConversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0.rawValue)
                                }
                            case Conversions.volume:
                                ForEach(VolumeConversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0.rawValue)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text("From")
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                        Picker("To conversion", selection: $selectionToConversion) {
                            switch selectionOfTypeOfConversion {
                            case Conversions.temperature:
                                ForEach(TemperatureConversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0.rawValue)
                                }
                            case Conversions.length:
                                ForEach(LengthConversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0.rawValue)
                                }
                            case Conversions.volume:
                                ForEach(VolumeConversions.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0.rawValue)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Text(output, format: .number)
                    } header: {
                        Text("To")
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            inputIsFocused = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func checkConvention() {
        if selectionOfTypeOfConversion == Conversions.temperature {
            selectionFromConversion = TemperatureConversions.celsius.rawValue
            selectionToConversion = TemperatureConversions.celsius.rawValue
        } else if selectionOfTypeOfConversion == Conversions.length{
            selectionFromConversion =  LengthConversions.meters.rawValue
            selectionToConversion = LengthConversions.meters.rawValue
        } else if selectionOfTypeOfConversion == Conversions.volume{
            selectionFromConversion =  VolumeConversions.milliliters.rawValue
            selectionToConversion = VolumeConversions.milliliters.rawValue
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

enum Conversions: String, CaseIterable {
    case temperature = "temperature"
    case length = "length"
    case volume = "volume"
}

enum TemperatureConversions: String, CaseIterable {
    var id: Self { self }
    
    case celsius = "celsius"
    case fahrenheit = "fahrenheit"
    case kelvin = "kelvin"
}

enum LengthConversions: String, CaseIterable {
    var id: Self { self }
    
    case meters = "meters"
    case feet = "feet"
    case miles = "miles"
}

enum VolumeConversions: String, CaseIterable {
    var id: Self { self }
    
    case milliliters = "ml"
    case pints = "pints"
    case gallons = "gallons"
}
```

Expecting: change the formula which counts input into output.

Comment: Hi @Anstasia, and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's _way_ too much code in your question that doesn't have anything to do with the problem you're having. Please take a look at [mcve], then update your code to show a _minimal_ example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Why doesn't your `enum Conversions` have an explicit `var id: ...`?

Comment: probably you want to use `.onChange(of: pickerSelection)` on the first two pickers, so you can set the following picker state accordingly.

Comment: @AshleyMills - thank you! I will be careful next time.

Comment: @meaning-matters I think that I don't need it